# Divider between items in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, split, actionbarsherlock, divider

I need to display dividers between my three items in actionBarSherlock. I found a solution that I needed to rewrite methods in ABS library in ActionMenuItemView needDividerBefore() to always return true, otherwise it would display divider only if there was an icon and text next to each other in consecutive items. So that´s what I did, then I set the divider to my ABS:

```
actionBar.setSplitBackgroundDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.separator));
```

But the divider is not visible. What´s wrong?

Comment: I would suggest use background image for splitting the items you're putting on the actionbar. By that I mean create a background image and set it for each item.